Why does fs.link() fail with EPERM whre fs.rename() succeeds?
I want to serve some static files under the directory /var/www   I would like to swap in a new set of files (which exist as, for example, /var/data/example) every few days or so.  The server does not follow symlinks (the host is Linux).
So the curious thing is that when I try a hardlink I get an EPERM:
fs.link('/var/data/example', '/var/www');

This is a bit surprising, since I can create /var/www.  What's more if I do this:
fs.rename(`/var/data/example', '/var/www')

it works!  I am mystified by this. I would rather use links, as it allows me to preserve what used to be there, rather than clobbering it.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Not usual to ask question in comments after posting an answer, but yet: why are you willing to do a hard link? Usually, unless there is a serious reason to do so, people prefer symlinks. For example because they are possible with directories. But also because you can do it accross filesystems.  hardlinks are for low level considerations, for people who cares about inodes, and about mounting points, and about filesystems. Not for web developpers who usually just want to store files and let underlying OS handle those tedious low level task for them ;-)

@chrslg The question explained why symlinks aren't chosen, it's not uncommon for them to not be processed properly. It's unknown if there's a real necessity for hard links when a copy could work

That is outside the scope of [so], but I am curious to know what is that server that does not follow symlinks. Apache does by default. Nginx doesn't, but can be configured to. Seems to me that this question (why I need hard link, and can the reason why I need it could not be solved) should be addressed. That being said, there is also (in addition to cp indeed) the option of mount --bind which is, sort of, a hard link on a dir. With the same drawbacks as hard-links)

I am doing this under a framework called Sandstorm.  I don't know any further details, but that's why the symlinks don't work.

As an additional remark, I've spent an entire career - and not a short one - using symlinks and ignoring hard links.  And then I find this situation where I can't use a symlink.  Thanks to all for curing my ignorance of hard links.

If this is a "quasi-devops" situation (I call that the fact that you don't really have the ability to alter the behaviour of components, only to assemble them together — even if not using docker and the other devops tools) maybe you should then consider mount --bind. Well, I don't think it would be healthy to use it a everyday synonym of ln. But if it is once, for one server, using one mount for the "root dir" of the server, using --bind to chose among several root dir candidates... it may be a solution (and you've the background to know if it is overkill or not)

From your example (you didn't explicitely say, but /var/www is usually a directory, so I take /var/data/example is too), it seems that your are trying to hard link a directory.
That can't be done on most filesystem (and in particular, can't be done with ext4, which is the most likely — tho I only guess from heuristic reasonning. /var/www means unix. Probably linux. So probably ext4).

This would be the information I was missing.

As noted in another answer, hard links don't generally work on directories. Any tools that allow this on arbitrary FS actually traverse a directory and link each file.
If this is the intention here then this needs to be done by traversing a directory recursively:
async function linkDir(sourceDir, targetDir) {
  await fsPromises.mkdir(targetDir, { recursive: true });
  const files = await fsPromises.readdir(sourceDir, { withFileTypes: true });

  for (const file of files) {
    const sourcePath = path.join(sourceDir, file.name);
    const targetPath = path.join(targetDir, file.name);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      await linkDir(sourcePath, targetPath);
    } else if (file.isFile()) {
      await fsPromises.link(sourcePath, targetPath);
    }
  }
}

It's unknown why link was preferred, but this approach is susceptible to any pitfalls that are inherent to it, e.g. the contents of a hard link can be accidentally modified and changed in other places, and a hard link needs to be unlinked first before it could be overwritten. In case this is undesirable, cp is a reasonable alternative.

My aim was to change the files presented via a  single change to the filesystem.  Doing it the way you propose will take several operations and present an empty, incomplete, or inconsistent file tree to the server, which is part of the Sandstorm framework and will stay in operation (not under my control) while I carry out this operation.

The question doesn't contain the context you're describing, it's unclear why this results in inconsistency. You can scan directory contents beforehand if you want file list to be more consistent. This wouldn't differ much from moving the files if target dir exists. Or you could create hard links before moving a dir in case you need to have a copy of it. Any way, that's it. You can use hard links if you want to save disk space and make this op faster, but can't use symlinks or move for some reason. It wasn't clear if this was the intention, or it was a misunderstanding what hard links are for
